# Writing a script to close screen session

Tags: bash, scripting, gnu, gnu-screen, detach

I have a bunch of screen sessions running on my machine, but all of them are detached and unneeded.  Is there a good way to just close all of them, so I have nothing when I type "screen -ls"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

how about

```
$killall screen
```

**Update**

Just to illustrate here are the lines from my machine where I tested this:

```
blake ~ $  screen -ls
There are screens on:
        10250.pts-0.web01       (Detached)
        446.pts-0.web01 (Detached)
        599.pts-0.web01 (Detached)
        526.pts-0.web01 (Detached)
4 Sockets in /tmp/screens/S-blake.

blake ~ $  killall screen
blake ~ $  screen -ls
No Sockets found in /tmp/screens/S-blake.
```

Comment: I don't think that will do anything to detached sessions.

Comment: Actually it will.  I just tested it on my machine and it wiped them all out

Comment: np ;-)  We've all been there at some point in time (Me more than most!)

Comment: You might want to use the `-u` option, though, to restrict the `killall` to just the user you intend, although if you aren't `su` or using `sudo` it won't let you kill another user's sessions. By the way, I had to do `killall screen.real`

Answer (score 3):

Had to use $ killall SCREEN for this to work.